# nested multiline comments in php

Tags: php, comments

I need to comment some lines of code that already contain other comments,
I tried to do something like this:

```
...
<?php /* ?>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <?php /* ?>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <?php */ ?>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<?php */ ?>
...
```

but it does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Multiple Line Comment inside Multiple Line Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977568/php-multiple-line-comment-inside-multiple-line-comment)

Answer (score 3):

From the PHP documents: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

> 'C' style comments end at the first */ encountered. Make sure you don't nest 'C' style comments. It is easy to make this mistake if you are trying to comment out a large block of code.

So you cannot nest multi-lined comments.

Comment: No. It might help if you were to edit you question or provide more information on what it is you're trying to do though. There could be other ways to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot. However, depending on what your code is actually doing, you may be able to get away with commenting out the HTML outputted by the php. Like this:

```html
<!--
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <?php /* ?>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <?php */ ?>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use multi-line php comment nested. Multi-line comment starts at the first